# nginx listens ok on 443 until 80 is redirected to it

Tags: nginx, unicorn

I have setup nginx with unicorn and it is acting strange. I tried to use same config for redirects which works on my other server, but on one server it does not work.
This works pretty well and it listens on 443

```
upstream app {
    # Path to Unicorn SOCK file, as defined previously
    server unix:/home/gittool/myapp/shared/sockets/unicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;

    server_name app.domain.com;

    root /home/gittool/myapp/public;

    try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app;

    location @app {
        proxy_pass http://app;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    client_max_body_size 4G;
    keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

If I add above server part this part for 80 redirect, not even 80 is not redirected to https but also https stops working and shows me there is wrong redirect

```
server {
      listen 80;
      server_name app.domain.com;
      return 301 https://app.domain.com$request_uri;
}
```

any clue what am I doing wrong? I use same config on other server which works ok

Comment: Have you tested the configuration using `nginx -t`?

Comment: Try adding an ipv6 listen directive for port 80

Comment: nginx -t shows all ok